# How to create fluid boxs float responsively using css nth Term

Tags: css, css-float, fluid-layout

I am trying to achieve a fluid seamless responsive layout with boxes using the nth term.

the exact layout i am trying to achieve is this http://dribbble.com/

The problem I have is making the boxes float together with no right margin on the last box. the float of boxes need to remain when re-sizing the browser.

please see my fiddle here. if you can help it would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvGCU/

```
 .box {

     position: relative;

     background: red;

     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

     -moz-border-radius: 3px;

     border-radius: 3px;

     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);

     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);

     box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);

     width: 21.3%;

     height: 200px;

     float: left;

     padding: 10px;

     margin-right:20px;

     ;

     margin-bottom:20px;

 }

 .box:nth-of-type(4n) {

     margin-right:0

 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1002px) {

     .box:nth-of-type(4n) {

         margin-right:0

     }
```

Comment: So unlike the dribbble.com example you need the boxes to remain 4 to a line?

Comment: Want it to be like the dribble example. respond to screen size eventually changing to only showing two boxes